# Laravel 7 store file in absolute path

Tags: php, storage, laravel-7

I have a vps that use custom folder to save a file, and they put the folder at the root of the system `/storage` but the website folder is at `/var/www/html/mywebsite` . Is there any way to configure laravel to store uploaded files to `/storage` folder?

Comment: You can change the storage driver settings and add new storage drivers in [config/filesystems.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/config/filesystems.php) . Your path would simply be `'/storage'` in this case since it's absolute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to say that using the `__DIR__` predefined constant will help:

```
__DIR__ . "/../../../storage/<something>"
```

**Edit:**

The route to go would be to create a new disk in your file system config.

```
'disks' => [
    'custom_folder_1' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'root'   => __DIR__ . '/../../../storage/path/to/your/new/storage/folder',
    ],
]
```